# CSS or jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Let's say there is the following HTML:

```
<div id="test">
   <span class="testSpan"></span>
</div>
```

There are two ways of selecting the `span` inside the `#test` div

(*I know I can select the span directly but this is not the point of the question*):

```
$('#test > .testSpan');
```

and

```
$('#test').find('.testSpan');
```

Which of these ways is the most optimal in terms of speed, browser compatibility or anything else?

Or there is no difference?

Comment: Maybe you should read this: https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/ First example is fitting your question quite good: `The .find() approach is faster because the first selection is handled without going through the Sizzle selector engine – ID-only selections are handled using document.getElementById(), which is extremely fast because it is native to the browser.`

Comment: http://jsperf.com/css-or-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will see this [JSPERF test](http://jsperf.com/find-select-speed-test/3) then you will see that `.find()` is definitely the better and faster way.

Actually `.find()` will select all the matching descendant elements(ie, child, child of child and so on...) whereas `>` is a direct child selector(ie, it will fetch the direct child).

Comment: While your answer is correct, would you be able to bring some stats in-line with your answer? Otherwise this answer depends on the presence of an external resource and, in the event of that resource falling over or being moved, becomes nothing more than an unsubstantiated assertion.

Comment: @DavidThomas:- Updated that!